# MySQL: How-to optimize query with two identical subqueries?

Tags: mysql

I have query that work fine, but it has 2 the same subqueries

```
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT count(O.id) FROM `offer` O WHERE O.product_id = P.id) AS poffers 
FROM `product` P 
JOIN product_section PS ON (PS.product_id = P.id AND PS.section_id IN (14)) 
WHERE P.deleted is NULL 
    AND (SELECT count(O.id) FROM `offer` O WHERE O.product_id = P.id) > 0
```

I try to optimize with JOIN, but new query returns empty result

```
SELECT *, OJ.pcount AS poffers
FROM `product` P 
JOIN product_section PS ON PS.product_id = P.id AND PS.section_id IN (14)
JOIN (SELECT count(O.id) AS pcount, O.product_id FROM `offer` O ) 
    AS OJ ON OJ.product_id = P.id
WHERE P.deleted is NULL AND OJ.pcount > 0
```

Than i try variables, but i think i use it wrong, query returns empty result

```
SELECT *,  
    @o := (SELECT count(O.id) FROM `offer` O WHERE O.product_id = P.id) 
    AS poffers 
FROM `product` P 
JOIN product_section PS ON (PS.product_id = P.id AND PS.section_id IN (14)) 
WHERE P.deleted is NULL 
    AND @o > 0
```

Comment: Do you have some example data? Perhaps you could set up a small example at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: how there add some data?

Comment: Try adding GROUP BY product_id to the subquery of your 1-st optimize attempt.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57570/1

Comment: its work :D work fast like it must be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the dependent subqueries. Instead, have one query which relates products to offer counts. This query you can use in several places. It will most likely be stored temporarily in memory, avoiding duplicate computations, but the database engine might do more clever things as well.

```
SELECT *, O.cnt AS poffers
FROM product P
JOIN product_section PS ON (PS.product_id = P.id AND PS.section_id IN (14))
JOIN (SELECT product_id, count(id) AS cnt
      FROM offer
      GROUP BY product_id
     ) O ON (O.product_id = P.id)
WHERE P.deleted is NULL AND O.cnt > 0
```

If the relation between P and PS is one-to-one, then you could even work without any subquerys whatsoever:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(O.id) AS poffers
FROM product P
JOIN product_section PS ON (PS.product_id = P.id AND PS.section_id IN (14))
JOIN offer O ON (O.product_id = P.id)
WHERE P.deleted is NULL
GROUP BY P.id
```

You also should consider whether there is a good reason to count a specific column. In most cases, `COUNT(*)` will be faster than `COUNT(col)`. The only reason to use the latter is if you explicitely want to exclude `NULL` values from the count.

Comment: this query the same in logic with my query #2

Comment: your second query like diEcho ones, and its very slow

Comment: If it is slow, that probably means you're missing some crucial keys. But I'm really surprised the first one doesn't work. Will need some test data.

Comment: @deerua, I [experimented](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c4df/7) a bit and found and fixed the error in my first query. Missed a `GROUP BY` there.

Comment: Funny thing that we both made the same mistake…

Answer (score 1):

give it a try ( not tested )

```
SELECT P.*,PS.*,count(O.id) AS oCount
FROM `product` P
INNER JOIN `product_section` PS ON (PS.product_id = P.id)
INNER JOIN `offer` O ON (O.product_id = P.id) 
WHERE P.deleted is NULL AND PS.section_id =14
GROUP BY O.product_id
HAVING oCount> 0
```

more optimized

```
SELECT P.*,PS.*,count(O.id) AS oCount
FROM `product` P
INNER JOIN (`product_section` PS,`offer` O) ON 
(PS.product_id = P.id AND O.product_id = P.id) 
WHERE P.deleted is NULL AND PS.section_id =14
GROUP BY O.product_id
HAVING oCount> 0
```

**TIPS:**

- dont use `*`, instead write only those column names which you want to retrieve
- make index on all columns which are using with `ON` & `WHERE` condition

[`Reference`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: its return 1 entry - must return 2

Comment: and oCount return 8 = sum of 2 entries

Comment: use my tips. change table engine to `innoDB`